# Check on which NextJs version is the project based

Tags: reactjs, next.js, command-line-interface, version, package.json

I am working on a NextJs project and I would like to know which NextJs version is installed. Where can I check that?

Comment: You can always check the package.json file.

Comment: Or you can simply run `npx next -v`

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 31):

You can view `package.json` of your project. Or You can use [**Next.js CLI**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli) In your project root directory enter command  `npx next --version`.

---

[image]

Comment: Great thanks man!

Comment: @Denis2310  You're welcome! ;-) Glad  I could help You !

Answer (score 7):

In the root directory of the project run

```
npx next -v
```

Hope this useful for you!

Comment: quick and easy!

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above upvoted answers I just wanted to add another way I have checked the `nextjs` version using `create-next-app`. I just followed below different steps

**1.** One way can to find the version like mention above from the `package.json` file as referred from below

[image]

**2.** Running below command

```
npx next --version
```

[image]

**3.** By running below commands

```
sudo npm install -g create-next-app@lates
create-next-app --version
```

[image]